# How do I share objects between multiple get requests in PHP?

Tags: php, web-services, rest, caching

I created a small and very simple REST-based webservice with PHP.
This service gets data from a different server and returns the result. It's more like a proxy rather than a full service.

```
Client --(REST call)--> PHP Webservice --(Relay call)--> Remote server
                        <-- Return data ---
```

In order to keep costs as low as possible I want to implement a caching table on the PHP webservice system by maintaining data for a period of time in server memory and only re-request the data after a timeout (let's say after 30 mins).

In pseudo-code I basically want to do this:

```
$id = $_GET["id"];
$result = null;

if (isInCache($id) && !cacheExpired($id, 30)){
    $result = getFromCache($id);
}
else{
    $result = getDataFromRemoteServer($id);
    saveToCache($result);
}

printData($result);
```

The code above should get data from a remote server which is identified by an id. If it is in the cache and 30 mins have not passed yet the data should be read from the cache and returned as a result of the webservice call. If not, the remote server should be queried.

While thinking on how to do this I realized 2 important aspects:

1. I don't want to use filesystem I/O operation because of performance concerns.
   Instead, I want to keep the cache in memory. So, no MySQL or local
   file operations.
2. I can't use sessions because the cached data must be shared across different users, browsers and internet connections worldwide.

So, if I could somehow share objects in memory between multiple GET requests, I would be able to implement this caching system pretty easily I think.

But how could I do that?

---

**Edit:** I forgot to mention that I cannot install any modules on that PHP server. It's a pure "webhosting-only" service.

Comment: With redis, memcached and other key-value in-memory storage engines

Comment: @dev-null-dweller I forgot to mention that I cannot install any modules on that PHP server. It's a pure "webhosting-only" service.

Comment: Could you simply specify a http caching header and put a caching http proxy in front of your app?

Comment: @Timo if you have filesystem I/O performance concerns, you should start with redefining your application environment. Heavy and efficient caching can not be done using typical webhosting setup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not implement the cache on the (PHP) application level. REST is HTTP, therefore you should use a caching HTTP proxy between the internet and the web server. Both servers, the web server and the proxy could live on the same machine as long as the application grows (if you worry about costs).

I see two fundamental problems when it comes to application or server level caching:

- using memcached would lead to a situation where it is required that a user session is bound to the physical server where the memcache exists. This makes horizontal scaling a lot more complicated (and expensive)
- software should being developed in layers. caching should not being part of the application layer (and/or business logic). It is a different layer using specialized components. And as there are well known solutions for this (HTTP caching proxy) they should being used in favour of self crafted solutions.

Comment: Good point. Putting a dedicated cache/proxy between the webservice and the client is probably the best way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you do have to use PHP, and you cannot modify the server, and you do want in-memory caching for performance reasons (without first measuring that any other solution has good enough performance), then the solution for you must be to change the webhosting.

Otherwise, you won't be able to do it. PHP does not really have any memory-sharing facilities available. The usual approach is to use Memcached or Redis or something else that runs separately.

And for a starter and proof-of-concept, I'd really go with a file-based cache. Accessing a file instead of requesting a remote resource is WAY faster. In fact, you'd probably not notice the difference between file cache and memory cache.